# Connection name on queue

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5, queue

I used redis for task queue in laravel, i want to use connection name per queue to handle config varibales conflict in queue in below code :

```
  php artisan queue:work connection-name --deamon --queue=high,medium,low --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

But i dont know what is the connection name in below code to use:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),

'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    'beanstalkd' => [
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'ttr' => 60,
    ],

    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'your-public-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id',
        'queue' => 'your-queue-name',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several connections configured.

Each connection is an element in the `connections` array and you just need to pass the relevant `key` as the name.

e.g.

```
php artisan queue:work sqs --daemon --queue=high --sleep=3 --tries=3
```